# Showing $U\otimes (V\oplus W) \cong U\otimes V \oplus U\otimes W $

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, direct-sum

I have to show $U\otimes (V\oplus W) \cong U\otimes V \oplus U\otimes W $ where $U,V,W$ are $K-$vector spaces. One way to give a linear map from left to right is: 
$$u\otimes (v,w)\mapsto (u\otimes v, u\otimes w).$$ This is well-defined since vectors of the form on the left span $U\otimes (V\oplus W)$.

I cannot find the inverse of this map. Please give me some hints for this!

Comment: Are they finite-dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: In that case you can use the dimension argument: both sides have the same dimension. ;-)

Comment: yes, they are finite dimensional.

Comment: @TroyWoo how to use dimension argument? I want to give an explicit isomorphism.

Comment: @ush you only need to argue injective, and then an injective linear map between two vector spaces of the same finite dimension is also surjective and therefore an isomorphism.

Comment: okay. Is the question also true in the case of infinite dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first map can be written as

$$F\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\otimes(v_i,w_i)\right)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\otimes v_i,\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\otimes w_i\right)$$

Now the inverse is 
$$F^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\otimes v_i,\sum_{j=1}^m u'_j\otimes w_j\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\otimes (v_i,0)+\sum_{j=1}^m u'_j\otimes (0,w_j).$$

Answer (score 3):

You can define tensor product by the [universal property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property). Then you just need to check that $U\otimes V\oplus U\otimes W$ satisfies the universal property for tensor product of $U$ and $V\oplus W$. This check is pretty much trivial. This approach is very useful, because it allows you to prove a lot of other similar identities, and not necessarily for finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Not every book taught universal property. Atiyah and Macdonald didnt use it, for one. So I guess not everybody is familiar with it. But you are right, man. It is very powerful, along with the category shxt. By the way, you from Cornell? Did you know Reyer? I once had a chance to talk to him.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some of the details implicit in @Sasha's answer.

> **Notation:** Given vectors spaces $X,Y$ and elements $x \in X$, $y \in Y$, I'll write $x \oplus y$ for the corresponding element of the vectors space direct sum $X \oplus Y$.

The map
\begin{align*}
 U \times  (V \oplus W) \to (U \otimes V) \oplus (U \otimes W) 
&&
(u, v \oplus w) \mapsto (u \otimes v ) \oplus (u \otimes w).
\end{align*}
is bilinear so, by the universality of the canonical bilinear map 
$$(u, v \oplus w) \mapsto u \otimes (v \oplus w) : U \times (V \oplus W) \to U \otimes (V \oplus W),$$ there is a unique linear map 
$$\Phi : U \otimes (V \oplus W) \to (U \otimes V) \oplus (U \otimes W)$$ 
such that 
\begin{align*}
\Phi(u \otimes (v \oplus w)) = (u \otimes v) \oplus (u \otimes w)
&& \text{ for all } u \in U, v \in V, w \in W.
\end{align*}

Similarly, the maps
\begin{align*}
U \times V \to U \otimes (V \oplus W) && (u,v) \mapsto u \otimes (v \oplus 0) \\
U \times W \to U \otimes (V \oplus W) && (u,w) \mapsto u \otimes (0 \oplus w)
\end{align*}
are bilinear, and so give rise to linear maps
\begin{align*}
\Psi_1  : U \otimes V \to U \otimes (V \oplus W) \\
\Psi_2 : U \otimes W \to U \otimes (V \oplus W)
\end{align*}
such that
\begin{align*}
\Psi_1(u \otimes v) = u \otimes (v \oplus 0) && \text{ for all } u \in U, v \in V \\
\Psi_2(u \otimes w) = u \otimes (0 \oplus w) && \text{ for all } u \in U, w \in W.
\end{align*}
By the universal property of vector space direct sum, $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ can be combined into a linear map 
$$\Psi : (U \otimes V) \oplus (U \otimes W) \to U \otimes (V \oplus W)$$
such that
\begin{align*}
\Psi( (u \otimes v) \oplus (u' \otimes w)) = u \otimes (v \oplus 0) + u' \otimes (0 \oplus w) && \text{ for all }u,u' \in U, v \in V, w \in W.
\end{align*}
One then checks that $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are inverse to one another (this can also be achieved using universal properties).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: pick bases for $U,V,W$ to induce bases for $U\otimes(V\oplus W)$ and $(U\otimes V)\oplus (U\otimes W)$. How does this prove the obvious map is an isomorphism between them?