# Showing that for any $R$-modules $U,\ V,\ W$ we have that $U\otimes(V\oplus W)\cong(U\otimes V)\oplus (U\otimes W)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, representation-theory, tensor-products

As the headline says, I want to show that for any $R$-modules $U,\ V,\ W$ we have that $U\otimes(V\oplus W)\cong(U\otimes V)\oplus (U\otimes W)$. **I know** that there has been questions for this before, but my question has to do with one of the answers in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902362/showing-u-otimes-v-oplus-w-cong-u-otimes-v-oplus-u-otimes-w) question.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and consider the two $R$-modules $U$ and $V\oplus W$. We know that there exists a tensor product
$$
\lambda :U\times (V\oplus W) \rightarrow U\otimes (V\oplus W),
$$
which satisfies the universal property: for any bilinear transformation $\phi:U\times (V\oplus W)\rightarrow X$, where $X$ is any $R$-module, there exists a unique homomorphism $\xi :U\otimes (V\oplus W)\rightarrow X$ such that $\xi\ \circ\lambda=\phi$.
Consider $\phi :U\times (V\oplus W)\rightarrow (U\otimes V) \oplus (U\otimes W)$ given by $\phi(u,v\oplus w):=(u\otimes v)\oplus(u\otimes w)$. Then
$$
\xi :U\otimes (V\oplus W)\rightarrow (U\otimes V) \oplus (U\otimes W)
$$
is a homomorphism given by $\xi(u\otimes(v\oplus w)):=(u\otimes v)\oplus(u\otimes w)$. If I can find an inverse
$$
\xi^{-1}:(U\otimes V) \oplus (U\otimes W)\rightarrow U\otimes (V\oplus W)
$$
of $\xi$, then I'm done, but I am not sure how to find that. In the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902362/showing-u-otimes-v-oplus-w-cong-u-otimes-v-oplus-u-otimes-w) I referred to earlier one of the answers wrote:

> the maps
> \begin{align*}
> U \times V \to U \otimes (V \oplus W) && (u,v) \mapsto u \otimes (v \oplus 0) \\
> U \times W \to U \otimes (V \oplus W) && (u,w) \mapsto u \otimes (0 \oplus w)
> \end{align*}
> are bilinear, and so give rise to linear maps
> \begin{align*}
> \Psi_1  : U \otimes V \to U \otimes (V \oplus W) \\
> \Psi_2 : U \otimes W \to U \otimes (V \oplus W)
> \end{align*}
> such that
> \begin{align*}
> \Psi_1(u \otimes v) = u \otimes (v \oplus 0) && \text{ for all } u \in U, v \in V \\
> \Psi_2(u \otimes w) = u \otimes (0 \oplus w) && \text{ for all } u \in U, w \in W.
> \end{align*}
> By the universal property of vector space direct sum, $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$ can be combined into a linear map
> $$\Psi : (U \otimes V) \oplus (U \otimes W) \to U \otimes (V \oplus W)$$
> such that
> \begin{align*}
> \Psi( (u \otimes v) \oplus (u' \otimes w)) = u \otimes (v \oplus 0) + u' \otimes (0 \oplus w) && \text{ for all }u,u' \in U, v \in V, w \in W.
> \end{align*}

and he says that we can identify $\Psi$ with $\xi^{-1}$. I understand how he obtains $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$ from the universal property, but I don't see why we can combine them into $\Psi$. Can someone make that part more clear?

Comment: For any two morphisms $\Psi_k:M_k\to N,$ simply define the morphism $\Psi:M_1\oplus M_2\to N$ by $\Psi(m_1,m_2)=\psi_1(m_1)+\Psi_2(m_2).$

Comment: @AnneBauval, thank you.